# sql list of records within a path scope

Tags: sql, sqlite, trim

I have a master table containing URLs:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MasterTable (url, masterId, PRIMARY KEY(url), UNIQUE(masterId));
```

An url string looks like this: `file:///Users/user1/Folder1/Folder2/.../FolderN/filename1.jpeg`.

Now, I need to write a query that for a path example `path = 'file:///Users/user1/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3'` will return all `masterId`s of filenames that are in this exact folder path but not further.

I guess I have to use some combination of `trim` functions but can't figure it out myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LIKE` and then count how many `'/'` are in the path to make sure you dont get deeper folders.

```
SELECT masterId
FROM MasterTable 
WHERE url like 'file:///Users/user1/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/%'
  AND length(url) - length( replace(url, '/', '') ) = 8
```

more generic:

```
 AND length(url) - length( replace(url, '/', '') ) = 
     length('file:///Users/user1/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/') 
   - length( replace('file:///Users/user1/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/', '/', '') )
```

Comment: I think this will return also masterIds for url like: `'file:///Users/user1/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/filename1.jpeg'`

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough. I've now edited it, let me know if it is still unclear. Thanks!

Comment: But that's not generic. What if the path is something else?

Comment: I'm trying something like: `WHERE url like 'file:///Users/user1/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/%' AND NOT LIKE ''file:///Users/user1/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/%/%'

Comment: Im getting syntax error on `Folder3/%/%'`. Do you know why?

Comment: Not sure. maybe you can try `regexp` or my length aproach